# I want to download a proxylist with curl in php

Tags: php, curl, proxy, php-curl

I want to download a proxy list with this api:
`https://api.proxyscrape.com?request=getproxies&proxytype=http&timeout=5000&country=US&anonymity=elite&ssl=yes`

how can I do it in php with curl???

**When you open this url, It will automatically download a text file with proxies.**

I want to download and place it in the current directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be using file_get_contents() function built into PHP.

So to download & save the file you would do something like this:

```
$proxies = fopen("proxies.txt", "w");
fwrite($proxies, file_get_contents('https://api.proxyscrape.com?request=getproxies&proxytype=http&timeout=5000&country=US&anonymity=elite&ssl=yes'));
fclose($proxies);
```

Comment: ```file_put_contents("proxies.txt",file_get_contents("https://api.proxyscrape.com?request=getproxies&proxytype=http&timeout=5000&country=US&anonymity=elite&ssl=yes"));``` also don't use `w`, use `wb` (or if you actually want text mode, use it explicitly eg `wt`)